# Issue withh Manage Workflow option on DNN 7.4.2

Tags: workflow, dotnetnuke

I am using DNN 7.4.2 version for my project now i want to implement Workflow Management for HTML content module.

I am able to apply Workflow but not able to create new Workflow and even not able to see button "Manage Workflow"

Please guide which version of DNN should i use and its paid or free ?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow API and tables are part of the DNN Platform, but the user interface to create new workflows is a professional feature. The Workflow Management module is part of all of the Evoq products (Engage, Content, and Content Basic). It's also on the Admin > Workflow Management page in any of the Evoq versions.

[Request a 30-day trial of Evoq Content](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/evoq-free-trial) and review what professional features you need beside the workflow management and discuss licensing costs with DNN Corp.

If you don't need any of the professional features and want to stick with the free DNN Platform, you can still do a custom workflow, but would need to create it directly in the database by inserting records into the Workflow, WorkflowStates, and WorkflowStatePermissions tables.